# How to I only read 'drive' network_type from .osm file in osmnx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

Usually I am reading some OSM data into a graph to only contain driven roads by specifying the bounding box via:

`ox.graph_from_bbox(43.54645, 43.54235, -96.73444, -96.72649, network_type='drive')`

The graph of the above bounding box looks like (when plotted with osmnx):

[image: Graph from bounding box coordinates]

Right now, I wish to read directly from an .osm file exported directly from selecting the same bounding box coordinates as above from the OSM website, and I am calling:

`ox.graph_from_xml(file_path)`

However the problem now is that there are way more nodes and edges, as seen in the graph below:

[image: Graph from .xml file]

I suspect that it has to do with the fact that I didn't specify the network type to only contain drivable surfaces. However, there is no option whereby I can specify this within the `graph_from_xml` function. So how do I reduce the 2nd graph (from the .osm file) to look like the first (from the bbox coordinates)?

Answer (score 0):

The `graph_from_xml` function does not accept a `network_type` argument because you're not querying for anything. You're just loading the contents of that file into a graph model. Docs: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.osm_xml

If you want to filter your file's contents, you should do that when you create the file itself, before you load it into OSMnx. Or, if absolutely necessary, you can load the complete file into OSMnx then manually remove edges you don't want by looping through them, checking their type, adding their `(u, v, key)` tuple identifier to a list of they're of an undesired type, then removing them all from your graph with `networkx.remove_edges_from()`.